# table thead with vertical text and text-overflow

Tags: html, css

I was searching here this problem and thanks to some people i found what i want, but, there is still one more thing that i want to do and that is text-overflow on vertical text.
So far this technique work great on horisontal text

```css
td {
  max-width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

But here won't work how i want it to. Text need to be hidden with dots do the end, if you know what i mean

```css
.container {
 width: 1058px;
 margin: 100px auto;
}
.table-frame table {
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 12px;
}
.table-frame table,
.table-frame th,
.table-frame td {
 border: 1px solid #010101;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}
.table-frame thead {
 background-color: #AAA;
}
.sector td {
 vertical-align: top;
}
.sector th,
.sector td {
 text-align: left;
 
}
.sector thead tr {
 height: 150px;
}
.sector thead tr th:first-child {
 width: 150px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.sector th.rotate {
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.sector th.rotate > div {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-frame sector">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Some text some text some text</th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1 text need to be hidden with dots</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hey can you show us demo with jsfiddle ..?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara 2nd code is demo, but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9da6ya2g/) it is. Text is invisible because overflow, but its without dots, and that is what i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you could use fixed dimensions give the text-overflow properties:

```
 white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 130px;
```

Here's a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kLzg7gr3/1/

Comment: Yes i can, and yes, i tried also what you do here, but on wrong element :D Thank you bro ;)

Comment: @soullighter I'm glad to have helped you! ;)